# Algorithm to calculate difference in users' tastes

Tags: algorithms, matching, recommender-system

I have data like Person $A$ like movies `['X','Y', 'Z']` and he dislikes `['V']`. Person $B$ like movies `['X','L','V']` and  dislikes `['Y']`. like wise so many users. What could be a good algorithm to find mean difference of users' tastes?

Comment: Depends on application... Any more details? #s of movies and users? Where do you want to use this dissimilarity?

Comment: I would like to find the similar taste users and suggest them as friends to follow. So there will be N number of movies and X Number of users. Each like the movie based on their taste. I don want to look for category of movie. I want the matching percentage of similarity among users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is called "Collaborative Filtering". Searching the web will offer you a tremendous amount of resources for this topic, but I truly recommend this paper:

[Xiaoyuan Su & Taghi M. Khoshgoftaar: A Survey of Collaborative Filtering Techniques](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/aai/2009/421425/)

In section *3. Memory-Based Collaborative Filtering Techniques* you'll find the basic  techniques to find users with similar taste. They generally consist of selecting a metric for a nearest-neighor-approach plus some modifications on the user-item-matrix (how to deal with missing values / how to treat items which have not been rated this often etc.).This is a good point to start.

After grasping the basic ideas you may want to try out some sophisticated techniques like Singular Value Decomposition, which has been successfully applied in the [Netflix-Price](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netflix_Prize) (you'll find a link to this and other techniques in section *4. Model-Based Collaborative Filtering Techniques of the recommended paper*).

If you have some bucks to spend, I also recommend "Programming Collective Intelligence" by Toby Segaran, which approaches this topic in a very very practical way.

Answer (score 1):

If you represent each movie as a categorical variable with 3 levels (like, unspecified, dislike) you can do any type of clustering analysis on your users with these covariates.

Comment: you mean to say like
 Fn(A,B) = C[like, unspecified, unlike]
         = C[1, 2, 2]
like    = A & B like X = 1
dislike = SUM (A dislike on B's like = V, B dislike on A's like = Y) = 2
unspecified = Z, L = 2
is that correct?

Comment: Ananth, I would also consider assigning a value to matches of dislikes.  In other words, A & B both dislike X implies some degree of similarity in tastes.  You may want to weight it differently than matching likes, but it should have relevence.